# Connect By hierarchical query oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have the following output from a query. I want to get one column with all the distinct values from 3 columns in one query.I am not able to decide  if it can be achieved by connect by or some other function.

```
Dad     Mom    Child
------  ----   -----
D006    M026    LA019
D006    M026    NP082
D005    M048    NG073
```

Expected output:

```
D006
D005
M026
M048
LA019
NP082
NG073
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A union with a CTE is simpler, but if you're on 11g you could unpivot the columns:

```
select distinct person
from (
  select *
  from (
    -- this is your real big query
    select 'D006' as dad, 'M026' as mom, 'LA019' as child from dual
    union all select 'D006', 'M026', 'NP082' from dual
    union all select 'D005', 'M048', 'NG073' from dual
  )
  unpivot (person for anyone IN (dad AS 'DAD', mom AS 'MOM', child AS 'CHILD'))
);

PERSON
------
D006   
NP082  
M026   
LA019  
M048   
D005   
NG073  

 7 rows selected
```

The unpivot operation adds a new column indicating which of the original columns the value came from; since you aren't apparently interested in that it can be discarded, but that has to be done in an outer query.

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/99798/1) showing the inner query with the extra column added by the unpivot, and the same thing wrapped in an outer query to get rid of it and remove duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Union` to combine the different columns into single columns which will also avoid `duplicates`

```
SELECT Dad FROM yourtable
UNION
SELECT Mom FROM yourtable
UNION
SELECT Child FROM yourtable
```

Update :

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Dad,Mom,Child
         FROM   bigquery) 
SELECT Dad FROM cte
UNION
SELECT Mom FROM cte
UNION
SELECT Child FROM cte;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is there any other option than UNION, can we use table function sys.odcivarchar2list()) and pass columns in it. I tried but it is not accepting column,maybe I m not doing it right

Comment: That table is a again a big query, so wanted to call it once

Comment: @RajA -  If it is a result of big query then use `CTE`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, my ADF programmer doesn't want to use WITH :-)

Comment: @RajA - does your ADF programmer have an arbitrary dislike of CTEs, or is there a practical reason not to use the appropriate tool for the requirement?

Comment: @Alex Poole - Actually they dont want to use "Expert" mode in ADF, they are using "Normal "mode. In Expert / Extended mode, with  clause can be used